# dinamic nested menu php

Tags: php, sql, menu

I have a table menu like this

i have problem to display like this with ul and li tag like 2nd picture.
please help me for the solution

menu_code|desc_code
1 | menu 1
1.1 | menu 1.1

1.2 | menu 1.2
1.2.1| menu 1.2.1
2 | menu 2
 i want to display my table menu with concept "unlimited level menu".

Comment: So what have you tried? This isn't a code writing website

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider changing your table structure. You will need to loop through each parent and children, you wouldnt want to do that with string splitting. I advice you to create an extra column parent_id and binding your items like that. After that its easy to crawl recursively through its children to create a ul > li structure.

Example recursive function:

```
public static function buildTree($items, $parent_id = null) {
    $result = [];

    foreach($items as $item) {
        if($item->parent_id == $parent_id) {
            $children = self::buildTree($items, $item->id);

            if($children) {
                $item->children = $children;
            }

            $result[$item->id] = $item;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

After that you can use the result of the build function to recursively create your menu structure:

```
public static function treeToHtml($tree, $level = 0) {
    $result = '';

    $result .= '<ul>';
    foreach($tree as $item) {
        $has_children = isset($item->children) && count($item->children) > 0;

        if($has_children) {
            $result .= '<li><a href="#">';
            $result .= self::treeToHtml($item->children, $level + 1);
            $result .= '</li>';
        } else {
            $result .= '<li><a href="#"></li>';
        }
    }

    $result .= '</ul>';

    return $result;
}
```

Edit function accordingly and statically all depends on the context you're using it in.

Comment: Thanks Niek Van der Maaden...your logic very helpfull :)